# Wordpress - integration a WooCommerce class WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product and another plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I want to extent the functionality of a plugin called "Royal addons" and it's module woogrid. WooGrid module helps to display woocommerce product in elementor builder in various ways. I want to extent "manual selection" part, so that after selecting a product it creates a duplicate of that product in woocommerce (via build-in class [WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Admin-Duplicate-Product.html)).

And after selection, it will display the duplicated product
So, to do the mentioned above duplication , I need to add a function that duplicates a product using woocommerce class WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product - here is it

```
public function duplicate_selected_products( $selected_products ) {
    if ( empty( $selected_products ) || ! class_exists( 'WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product' ) ) {
        return [];
    }

    $duplicated_products = [];
    
    
    foreach ( $selected_products as $product_id ) {
        $duplicate_product = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product();
        $new_product_id = $duplicate_product->product_duplicate( $product_id );
        if ( $new_product_id ) {
            $duplicated_products[] = $new_product_id;
        }
    }

    return $duplicated_products;
    }
```

And the problem is that When I add this function to the file with woogrid module (called wpr-woo-grid.php) Wordpress doesn't access the woocommerce class

it shows an error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class WprAddons\Modules\WooGrid\Widgets\WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product' not found in /home/winecard/public_html/wp-content/plugins/royal-elementor-addons/modules/woo-grid/widgets/wpr-woo-grid.php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNvaX.png)

I tried to use there requests with location of origial file

require_once '/home/winecard/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/include/admin/class-wc-admin-duplicate-product.php';

require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-duplicate-product.php';

require PATH_THIRD . 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php';

I used this "$duplicate_product = new WooCommerce\Admin\WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product();
instead of this "$duplicate_product = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product();"

but this doesn't work

How could I access the class woocommerce at royal addons plugin? thank you for your reply!